# How to add dashboard templates (Bootstrap 4 Admin Template) js files to rails 7?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-7

I trying to integrate bootstrap 4 admin dashboard to rails 7 but my js files are not working and css files are working.
s links in my file.html

```
<script src="js/vendor/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/chartjs-plugin-datalabels.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/datatables.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/perfect-scrollbar.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/glide.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/progressbar.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/jquery.barrating.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/select2.full.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/nouislider.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/Sortable.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/mousetrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/dore.script.js"></script>
<script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
```

This what I have been trying in my views/layout/application.html.erb

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'vendor/jquery-3.3.1.min', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'vendor/bootstrap.bundle.min', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'vendor/Chart.bundle.min', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'vendor/chartjs-plugin-datalabels', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'vendor/moment.min', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'vendor/fullcalendar.min', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'vendor/datatables.min', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'vendor/perfect-scrollbar.min', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'vendor/glide.min', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'vendor/progressbar.min', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'vendor/jquery.barrating.min', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'vendor/select2.full', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'vendor/nouislider.min', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'vendor/bootstrap-datepicker', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'vendor/Sortable', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'vendor/mousetrap.min', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'dore.script', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'scripts', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)